# Describing element using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, describe-object

The attached picture shows my result on ArcGIS Pro. It shows all the elements in a geodatabase that a user chooses.

[image]

It only displays catalogpath to the elements, but now I need to describe, for  each of these element such as Q:\ClassData\317\2020\HwyCorridor.gdb\rawdata, other descriptions. For now, I just want to figure out how to extract the information of shapetype, and display it right under the catalogpath.

The two codes with my comment are the ones I am struggling with. If I take out these two, the code runs without any error and gives me the result as shown in the attached picture.

```
def data_report(workspace):

elements = defaultdict(list)

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for dirname in dirnames:  # 'FeatureDataset'
        desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname))
        elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)


    for filename in filenames:
        desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
        elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)

report = []

for element_type, element_list in elements.items():
    report += [f"{element_type}:"]
    for element_description in element_list:
        report +=  [f"\t\t{element_description['catalogPath']}"] 
        #Describe the element
        desc2 = arcpy.da.Describe(element_description['catalogPath'])

#If Datatype is featureclass, add its shapetype to the report
if dataType == featureClass:
    report+= [f"\t\t\{"Shape Type :   " + desc.shapeType}")]

return report
```

Comment: The way I inspect dictionaries, lists, sets, etc is to print them. The code that you’ve presented includes no print statements.

Comment: Please in future when you get an error with your python code, include the entire exception text (*not* just the final error message) as text, formatted as `code` using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 2):

`arcpy.da.Describe` returns a dictionary not a `Describe` object like the old `arcpy.Describe` function.  As such, it doesn't have a `.shapeType` property, it has a `shapeType` *key*, i.e `element_description['shapeType']`. I suggest you inspect the dictionary and also have a look at the `arcpy.da.Describe` documentation to see what keys you can use.

You're also misusing the `f"format string"`.  You don't concatenate, you just use the variable inside `{}` in the string, i.e.

```
report+= [f"\t\t\"Shape Type :  {element_description['shapeType']}")]
```

Note that `da.Describe` is ArcGIS Pro only and `f"{format}"` strings are Python 3 only